# How interchangeable are stacked washers?

Tags: washer

I have a **stacked** 27" [washer](https://products.geappliances.com/MarketingObjectRetrieval/Dispatcher?RequestType=PDF&Name=360330_gtun275emgm_c3.pdf)/dryer and I need to replace the washer (the drum is out of balance and it chews clothes).

Do I need to buy a new dryer too or maybe it is possible to replace just the washer?

(I want to buy a *front loader*, e.g., [WF45T6000AW](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Samsung-High-Efficiency-Stackable-Front-Load-Washer-White-ENERGY-STAR/1002890950))

Comment: Not a direct answer, hence a comment. I fit a work surface an inch or so above the washer, and the dryer sits on that. Means that when there's a problem, especially with the washer, it's easy to remove it separately, without disturbing the dryer. Depends of course on location, but the last one I did provided a nice shelf at the side, too!

Comment: Likewise, mounting the dryer on heavy duty shelf brackets (appropriately big ones) has been seen in the wild as a solution to this problem without involving the new washer. But Tim's approach *from the start* does solve the whole "servicing complicated" problem before the first appliance dies, as well as easily decoupling their deaths and replacements, whichever one dies first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are asking is; Can the washer part of your stacked unit be replaced with a new front load washer?

The simple answer is no.  Stackable washer/dryers are produced as a unit and are not separate washer and dryer components just attached one above the other.